# Showing that $p(x)\mapsto p'(x)$ is not a continous linear transformation

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand a result in Rynne & Youngson: Linear Functional Analysis.

Regarding continous linear transformations, the following is stated:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear  transformation. The following are then equivalent:
>
> 1. $T$ is uniformely continous.
> 2. $T$ is continous.
> 3. $T$ is continous at $0$.
> 4. There exists a positive real number $k$ such that $||T(x)||\le k||x||$ for all $x\in X$.

As an example of showing that a linear transformation is *not* continous, the authors consider the map $T:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}$ defined by $T(p)=p'$, where $\mathbb{P}$ is the linear subspace of $C[0,1]$ (continous functions on $[0,1]$) consisting of all polynomials, and $p'$ is the derivative of $p$.

In order to prove that $T$ is not continous, they take as an example $p_n\in\mathbb{P}$ defined by $p_n(x)=x^n$, meaning
\begin{align}
||p_n||=\sup\{|p_n(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}=1,
\end{align}
while 
\begin{align}
||T(p_n)||=||p'_n||=\sup\{|p_n'(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}=n.
\end{align}

The authors conclude that no $k\ge0$ can exist such that $||T(p)||\le k||p||$ for all $p\in\mathbb{P}$, and $T$ is not continous.

Now, this may be an amazingly stupid question, but what is stopping me from just setting $k=n$? Does the problem occur as $n$ tends towards infinity?

Comment: $k$ needs to be some fixed value but for ever $n\in \mathbb N$ you have $\|T(p_n)\|=n$ (emphasis on the "for every").

Comment: $n$ varies, $k$ must be fixed.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, I somehow didn't realize that $k$ had to be fixed for _all_ $p$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a stupid question...but in the statement "for all $p$, $\| T(p) \| \le k \| p \|$", where do you see $n$? The number $n$ isn't even part of that statement.

So your idea doesn't even quite make sense.

Comment: I was thinking that "Given any $p\in\mathbb{P}$, there must exist a corresponding $k$ such that $||T(p)||\le k||p||$", but failed to realize that the $k$ has to be fixed for all $p$. :)

Comment: Understood. The order of quantifiers can be a pain in the neck!